# RStudio server - set libPath for all users

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

How do I setup default `.libPaths()` for all users of RStudio server? I think I have to add something to `/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf`, but not sure what. Or do I have to modify `.Rprofile` of each user manually?

I am trying to have most of the libraries shared for users, installed in `/usr/lib/R/site-library/`.

We are running latest version of RStudio server on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem, `rsession-ld-library-path` did not help me as .libPaths() for user did not change by that.

Instead, I found it useful to change `/usr/lib64/R/etc/Renviron` file directly.
This file had `R_LIBS_USER` variable in it that I changed to the admin shared library that we wanted to enforce all users to default to.